# Electrical connection that is "AND NOT" gate

Tags: switches, mains

I need to create an electrical switch on normal net voltage (230V) that sort of acts like an "AND NOT" gate.

All I have at the moment is three copper wires and some connectors. Obviously, when I just connect them, I'll get power on C when A or B are powered.
What I need is power on C when A is powered and B is not.

How can I connect my wires to get this, or what do I need to buy in order to end up with what I need?

Comment: Are the voltages on A and B in phase with each other?

Comment: Yes I guess so. A and B are controlled by thermostats that cut or pass through net power.

Comment: Don't bet on them being in phase.

Comment: You can't implement 'not' with wires and switches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A changeover relay should do the trick, although I have made the following assumptions:

1. `C` is allowed to draw power from `A`.
2. You have a Neutral/non-earth return path for the coil and `B`.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw0YoD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- No power from A? No power to C.
- Power from B? No power to C.

Comment: You've just made a nice 60 Hz buzzer which will destroy the relay in a matter of hours.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev How so? A relay with a coil suitable for AC operation is implied in the answer, as are appropriate contact specifications.

Comment: Ok, [got it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pmVHQ.png). Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a single change over (C/O) relay, with its coil powered from B - use the normally closed (NC) contacts to connect C to A